# Skorohod convergence (space of right continuous functions with left limit)

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, skorohod-space

If $f_n$ is a sequence of functions of the Skorohod Space $D([0,\infty),E)$, where $E$ is a separable Banach space, such that $f_n \to f$ in the Skorohod topology. Is it possible that there exists a $t \in [0,\infty)$ such that $\sup_n||f_n(t)||=+\infty$? I think the answer is no and I also think the proof shouldn't be so complicated, but for some reason I'm struggling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us fix $t$. As $f$ is cadlag, it is bounded around $t$: $$
\sup_{|t-s|\le t/2} |f(s)| \le M 
$$
I use [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g) notations.

Now for $n$ large enough, 
$$
\inf_\lambda \max \left[
\sup_{|t-s|\le t/2} |\lambda(s) - s|,
\sup_{|t-s|\le t/2}|f_n(\lambda(s)) - f(s)| 
\right]\le \epsilon $$so there is a certain $\lambda_\epsilon$ such as 
$$
{|t-s|\le t/2}\implies |\lambda_\epsilon(s) - s|\le 2\epsilon,
|f_n(\lambda_\epsilon(s)) - f(s)| \le 2\epsilon
$$

Now let $t_\epsilon = \lambda_\epsilon^{-1}(t)\in 
\lambda_\epsilon^{-1} ([t\pm 2\epsilon])
\subset [t\pm t/2]$ for $\epsilon$ small enough.

Then
$$
|f_n(t)| \le |f_n(\lambda_\epsilon(t_\epsilon)) - f(t_\epsilon)| 
+ |f(t_\epsilon)| \le M +2\epsilon \le 2M
$$

Comment: thanks, very neat! The same proof works to show even more: $\sup_{n,t\in [0,T]} ||f_n(t)||<\infty$ for each $T>0$.